# Verifying OpenID signature

Tags: openid, signature, verify

I am failing to verify an OpenID signature. This is what I do, please tell me what's wrong:

These are the values I get when associating:

```
mac_key 3E2FH8mCR/OJ3/T6N3UPqD8iYf0fXyQ0c4io5psTC7s=
assoc_handle AMlYA9WWc0Jk8BnTg9E0cvczK8DYBediGvu5snBaYec9uFlTj3wbY9ezQepX-kFv2foRGQC6
```

I am redirecting the client to:

`https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.return_to=http://www.sdfanq.com/checkauth&openid.realm=http://www.sdfanq.com/&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.assoc_handle=AMlYA9WWc0Jk8BnTg9E0cvczK8DYBediGvu5snBaYec9uFlTj3wbY9ezQepX-kFv2foRGQC6`

Uppon accepting, the client is redirect back to:

```
http://www.sdfanq.com/checkauth?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fud&openid.response_nonce=2012-05-23T05%3A54%3A30Z0Sv8nDqIrrWYeQ&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sdfanq.com%2Fcheckauth&openid.assoc_handle=AMlYA9WWc0Jk8BnTg9E0cvczK8DYBediGvu5snBaYec9uFlTj3wbY9ezQepX-kFv2foRGQC6&openid.signed=op_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle&openid.sig=HtlEGDEmee1UsH9fZg%2BQXt3JCyk11Lb7RMTNEcxbCKo%3D&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawlUNTJm8YX2SyJ2QXsg9eBe3g0LNnKKXwY&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawlUNTJm8YX2SyJ2QXsg9eBe3g0LNnKKXwY
```

To verify the signature I concatenate the keys like this:

```
op_endpoint:https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud\nclaimed_id:https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawlUNTJm8YX2SyJ2QXsg9eBe3g0LNnKKXwY\nidentity:https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawlUNTJm8YX2SyJ2QXsg9eBe3g0LNnKKXwY\nreturn_to:http://www.sdfanq.com/checkauth\nresponse_nonce:2012-05-23T05:54:30Z0Sv8nDqIrrWYeQ\nassoc_handle:AMlYA9WWc0Jk8BnTg9E0cvczK8DYBediGvu5snBaYec9uFlTj3wbY9ezQepX-kFv2foRGQC6\n
```

Now when I base64.encode(hmac256("3E2FH8mCR/OJ3/T6N3UPqD8iYf0fXyQ0c4io5psTC7s=", S)), where 'S' is the concatenated string, I get a wrong value.

Comment: Were you able to get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 3):

you forgot to base64 decode the key. as a general rule of thumb: if something looks like base64, it's not a bad Idea to at least try decoding it.

Try this:

```php
<?php
$string="op_endpoint:https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
claimed_id:https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawlUNTJm8YX2SyJ2QXsg9eBe3g0LNnKKXwY
identity:https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawlUNTJm8YX2SyJ2QXsg9eBe3g0LNnKKXwY
return_to:http://www.sdfanq.com/checkauth
response_nonce:2012-05-23T05:54:30Z0Sv8nDqIrrWYeQ
assoc_handle:AMlYA9WWc0Jk8BnTg9E0cvczK8DYBediGvu5snBaYec9uFlTj3wbY9ezQepX-kFv2foRGQC6
"; //first we take the string to be signed

$key=base64_decode("3E2FH8mCR/OJ3/T6N3UPqD8iYf0fXyQ0c4io5psTC7s="); //the key needs to be Base64 decoded.

$orisig="HtlEGDEmee1UsH9fZg+QXt3JCyk11Lb7RMTNEcxbCKo="; //take the original signature to check it later

$truesig=base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256",$string,$key,true)); //calculate the signature you get

echo $truesig."<br>".$orisig."<br>"; //output both
var_dump($orisig==$truesig) //and show they are the same.
?>
```

I hope it's not a problem to solve these really old questions.